# Teradata SQL Concatenates Columns when Pasting to Excel

Tags: sql, excel, teradata, copy-paste, teradata-sql-assistant

I have my SQL output as five columns. When I paste the SQL output to Excel it seems to concatenate everything that is a string into one column until a number appears.

In this case, my first 4 columns are text and Excel they are concatenated to one column. My fifth column is a number and that's in the 2nd column in Excel. My column headers are all concatenated to a single cell.

When I paste to NotePad it looks fine. And even when I paste to a text box inside of Excel it looks fine. But when I go to paste the data from NotePad and the text box I get the same thing.

Does anyone know a solution for this? And is this an Excel or SQL issue?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the Text to Columns in my Excel settings got switched to comma instead of tab. Go to Data > Text to Columns > choose delimited and then choose tab.